# How to clear touch screen "touched" button focus, active, hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Trying to figure out how to reset a button back to the "untouched" state. I am using a button as:

```
    <div id="service-control-buttons" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
        <a href="#" id="service-previous" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-l">Prev</a>
        <a href="#" id="service-next" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right">Next</a>
    </div>
```

When I tap (on my iPad) Next or Prev it runs a javascript function I wrote and then the button remains permanently active, hovered or focused (not sure the state).

My goal: After the javascript function runs, I want to reset the button back to the un-active, un-hovered or un-focused state. Of course, this doesn't happen on non-touch screen mouse click.

I've tried:

```
$(another-selecter).focus();
$(another-selecter).click();
$('#service-next').blur();
```

Also

```
$('#service-next').css('background-color', 'original-color')
```

works but of course, that's the end of the highlighting altogether and I don't want that. I don't want to manually set css as I use themes that may change in the future and want to avoid hacks if possible.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent this, you can customize the hover effects for touch screens using the following @media in you CSS file.

```
@media (hover: none) and (pointer: coarse) {
   /* Add hover styles here */
}
```

**Use Case Example**

Lets say we have a button with id `btn-one` that has a transparent bg color but the hover effect changes it to red.

By applying the code below, when a user with a touch device interacts with the app, the @media will trigger style changes. Keeping the bg color transparent on hover. In this way we can prevent the button having a sticky behavior.

By the contrary if the device isn't a touch screen the hover styles will work as if this @media doesn't exist, and so the bg colors will change on hover, normally.

```
@media (hover: none) and (pointer: coarse) {
  #btn-one:hover {
    background-color: transparent!important;
    color: black;
  }
}
```